# Positioning stacked divs at the bottom of a container

Tags: css

I'm building a staked bar graph in PHP. I need it to look like this:

[image]

Currently I am able to stack-up the gray and red values, but they are at the top of the .graph container. How do I align them at the bottom? I tried vertical-align: bottom but it did not really work.

```
<div class="graph">
    <div class="bar">
        <div class="views" style="height:'.$showViews.'px"></div>
        <div class="actions" style="height:'.$showActions.'px"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.graph {


  width: 200px;
    height: 32px;
    border-top: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.graph .bar {
    width: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1px;
    height:30
}
.graph .bar .views {
    background-color: #ccc
}
.graph .bar .actions {
    background-color: red
}
```

[Here's my code on JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HHnRQ/1/).

Thanks.

Comment: HTML is not really meant for accurate presentation, perhaps an SVG based solution would be easier?

Comment: .graph .bar {  position: absolute; bottom: 0;};.graph { position: relative; } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:absolute` will make your life easier!

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/RZ8ye/1/

Basically, we're using `position:absolute` to stack the elements on top of one another. By giving the parent positioning (in our case, "`relative`"), we position the stacked elements relative to that. We set `bottom`, `left`, and `right` and then define the `height` with an inline style (percentage based, based on the parent)

Answer (score 0):

just added `position:relative` value in CSS.

here is the modified code.

```
.graph .bar .views 
{  
background-color: #ccc; 
height:10px; /*height can be added dynamically*/
position:relative;
}
.graph .bar .actions 
{
background-color: red;
position:relative;
height:20px;
}
```

HTML looks like same as posted .

```
<div class="graph">
    <div class="bar">
            <div class="views" style="height:'.$showViews.'px"></div>
            <div class="actions" style="height:'.$showActions.'px"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="bar">
            <div class="views" style="height:'.$showViews.'px"></div>
            <div class="actions" style="height:'.$showActions.'px"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/HHnRQ/1/